# is it possible to track the requested domain name for dummy data import wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to track requested domain.com, is coming on our site.

Actually I am giving wordpress import data from our site by dummy content generated import/export xml file.

For Example:- project.domain.com is my site and someone request to import data on www.someone-domain.com so i want to store in db particular domain name like www.someone-domain.com.

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand what your question is. Could you give an example which is a bit better detailed? Maybe add some example code, etc. to show what your idea is? Thanks

Comment: Hello koljanep, Thanks for response                                 Actually I want to make wordpress theme and provide the dummy content xml file. When the user download my theme and import dummy content in it. I want to get the domain information where the user requested for dummy data.                                      Is it possible koljanep ??